Toga App Icon Not Displaying on Android: How to Fix?
I’m using Toga to develop an Android app and I've set an icon for the application, but it’s not displaying correctly. Here’s what I’ve done:
Placed the Icon File: I have a PNG icon file (F.png) located in the resources directory of my project.
Updated the main Function: I specified the icon path in the main function as icon='resources/F.png'.
Built the App: I ran briefcase build android and confirmed that the build was successful.
Despite these steps, the app icon is not showing up in the Android emulator or device.

The main function of your app can't change the icon displayed in your device's launcher, because that's determined before your app even starts. Instead, you need to configure this at the Briefcase level. See this page for a tutorial, and select the "Android" tab.

Thanks it worked. It's weird that I didn't found this on my search.
